# java negate boolean BiFunction

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

I have a class which will check if a key is/isn't included into a set of keys. This conditions are described in `Map` with use of `MathingType`s

```
public enum MatchingType {
    MATCH, MISMATCH
}
```

Map with matching type predicates

```
Map<MatchingType, Function<Set<String>, Predicate<String>>> predicateMap =
        Map.of(
                MATCH, set -> set::contains,
                MISMATCH, set -> not(set::contains)
        );
```

An example of usage

```
public boolean isKeyAvailable(String key, MatchingType matchingType, Set<String> keys) {
    return predicateMap.get(matchingType)
                       .apply(keys)
                       .test(key);
}
```

Now I see that code from above is possible to refactor with the use of `BiFunction`.

```
Map<MatchingType, BiFunction<Set<String>, String, Boolean>> predicateMap =
        Map.of(
                MATCH, Set::contains,
                MISMATCH, Set::contains //how to negate?
        );

public boolean isKeyAvailable(String key, MatchingType matchingType, Set<String> keys) {
    return predicateMap.get(matchingType)
                       .apply(keys, key);
}
```

But how does it possible to negate `Set::contains`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [java-11](/questions/tagged/java-11) there is a static method [`Predicate.not(Predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#not(java.util.function.Predicate)) however, there is not such method in [`BiPredicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html).

You might want to use `BiPredicate` as is with its instance method [`negate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html#negate--), which is available since its release as of [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8):

```
BiPredicate<Set<String>, String> biPredicate = Set::contains;
    
Map<MatchingType, BiPredicate<Set<String>, String>> biPredicateMap =
    Map.of(
        MatchingType.MATCH, biPredicate,
        MatchingType.MISMATCH, biPredicate.negate()
    );
```

```
boolean result = biPredicateMap.get(matchingType)
                               .test(keys, key);
```

The `Function` based functional interface don't have negation since their lambda expressions are not guaranteed to return `Boolean`.

Comment: But it doesn’t hurt to use `Map.of(MatchingType.MATCH, Set::contains, MatchingType.MISMATCH, (s,o) -> !s.contains(o))`. Don’t know why people are so obsessed with method references.

Comment: @Holger: Maybe the OP's case is the lambda expression is too way long and the method reference would help a lot (that's why I also suggest to place `biPredicate` out of `biPredicateMap` as a separate field/variable . Remember we are always told to post always a *minimal* complete verifiable which here seems like `!s.contains(o)` would be better.

Comment: How can the lambda expression be way too long, when there is an equivalent method reference expression? It always boils down use either `TypeName::methodName` or `(a,b) -> a.methodName(b)`. I don’t see any scenario where using the method reference at all costs would be justified.

Comment: I have no idea, just guessing. I only answered "*But how does it possible to negate Set::contains?*" the best I could. I feel it's a matter of preference. Moreover, people rather oversee the `!` operator at the beginning than the negation method - also my opinion.